# When I turn on the servo it spins on its own before going to the right position and start the sketch

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, sketch, code-review

I can't get my head around this: when I turn the servo on it just spins on its own as if it's setting up, it goes to an angle superior to the one I want it to go. (Don't mind if it has to set up but it can't spin more than 20 degrees which is currently doing).

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards    
int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

int degrees_of_motion = 20;
int servo_speed = 88;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(3);  // attaches the servo on pin 3 to the servo object
  myservo.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= degrees_of_motion; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos); // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(servo_speed); // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = degrees_of_motion; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
    // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos); // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(servo_speed);// waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Humm, all the methods in object myservo are available after you instantiate it.  So try initializing before you attach the servo (swap lines in your setup() method).  Also be careful not to write a negative number to the servo.  I don't think you are doing it.  But just keep it in mind as the driver might interpret it as a really large number.

Comment: st2000 Do you mean swapping  myservo.attach(3);
  myservo.write(0). It doesn't make a difference also tried to put int after void setup. Was this what you meant?

Comment: If you remove the positioning code in the `loop()` function so that the `setup()` does an attach followed by positioning the servo to 0 degrees, what happens? Also what if instead of the `for` loops in the `loop()` function you instead have a global variable for position which you set to zero degrees in `setup()` function and then have the logic in the `loop()` function just increment or decrement by 1 each time `loop()` is called?

Comment: If I remove the loop() function so that the setup() does an attach followed by positioning the servo to 0 degrees: Every time I turn it on it will spin to an unidentified angle really fast and come back to 0 and stop. Also global variable I am really new to Arduino not really sure what you mean. Thank you very much

Comment: the question title implies that the motor moves **before** you run the sketch. it that what happens?

Comment: Start simple.  Just power up the servo without connecting the control line to anything.  Most if not all normal servos should do nothing.  Maybe this servo is broken or behaves in unexpected ways. Perhaps the processor has been damaged. You might try a different Arduino Uno or at least a different PWM port on the same Arduino Uno.  Also, you might try a different servo library or write your own.

Comment: jsotola If I upload an empty sketch on the servo and power it nothing will happen.

Comment: Also tried a new arduino

Comment: Noise on the control line could cause random movement, try putting a pulldown on the control line; If this doesn't happen with an empty sketch that is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you have a sketch such as the following? This uses the `loop()` function of the Arduino sketch to do one movement each time the `loop()` function is triggered.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
                // twelve servo objects can be created on most boards    

int pos = 0;   // variable to store the servo position
int direc = 1; // direction and amount of position iteration, + to increment, - to decrement

int degrees_of_motion = 20;
int servo_speed = 88;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(3);  // attaches the servo on pin 3 to the servo object
  pos = 0;            // start off with zero degrees.
  direc = 1;          // start off incrementing the angle by 1
}

void loop() {
  if (direc > 0 && pos > degrees_of_motion) {
    direc *= -1;       // change the direction of iteration, keep amount
    pos = degrees_of_motion;
  }
  if (direc < 0 && pos < - degrees_of_motion) {
    direc *= -1;       // change the direction of iteration, keep amount
    pos = - degrees_of_motion;
  }

  myservo.write(pos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
  pos += direc;          // increment/decrement the position
  delay(servo_speed);    // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
}
```

Comment: Thank you but there is no difference with this sketch